# Interpolation is not smooth

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, interpolation, precision-and-accuracy

Consider a function

```
f[x_, Z_, α_, mN_, q_, R_, S_] = 
  Assuming[mN > 0 && x > 0, 
   9*α*Z^2/(2*Pi)*((1 + (1 - x)^2)/x)*
    (q^2 - x^2 mN^2)/q^4*
    SphericalBesselJ[1, 
      R*q]^2/(R*q)^2*
    Exp[-q^2*S^2]];
```

It is defined in the domain
$$
\text{max}[2\cdot 10^{-5}, x\cdot m_{N}]< q< q_{\text{max}} = 4.49/5, \quad 10^{-9}<x <q_{\text{max}}/m_{N}
$$
I'm trying to obtain the interpolation of numerical integral 
$$
\int \limits_{q_{\text{min}}}^{q_{\text{max}}}dq^{2}f[x,42,1/137,100,q,5,0.726]
$$
for the given value of x. Namely, I write

```
g1 = 
  Table[{x, 
    NIntegrate[
     f[x, q, 42, 1/137, 100, 5, 0.726]*2*q, {q, 
      Max[100*x, 2*10^-5], 4.49/5}]}, {x, 10^-9, 4.49/(5*100), 10^-4}];
g[x_] = Interpolation[g1 ][x]
```

Finally, I want to draw a plot of the function g[x]. I write

```
LogLogPlot[g[x], {x, 10^-9, 4.49/(5*100)}, PlotRange -> All]
```

And I see discontinuous plot. The point of discontinuity strongly depends on the table step size (I've tried from $10^{-7}$ to $10^{-2}$). From the other side, if I simply write

```
LogLogPlot[
 NIntegrate[
  Re[f[x, q, 42, 1/137, 100, 5, 0.726]]*2*q, {q, 
   Max[100*x, 2*10^-5], 4.49/5}], {x, 10^-9, 4.49/(5*100)}, 
 PlotRange -> All],
```

then the plot is smooth.

How to obtain correct interpolation?

The code sample is

```
 f[x_, Z_, α_, mN_, q_, R_, S_] = 
      Assuming[mN > 0 && x > 0, 
       9*α*Z^2/(2*Pi)*((1 + (1 - x)^2)/x)*
        (q^2 - x^2 mN^2)/q^4*
        SphericalBesselJ[1, 
          R*q]^2/(R*q)^2*
        Exp[-q^2*S^2]];

    g1 = 
      Table[{x, 
        NIntegrate[
         f[x, 42, 1/137, 100,q, 5, 0.726]*2*q, {q, 
          Max[100*x, 2*10^-5], 4.49/5}]}, {x, 10^-9, 4.49/(5*100), 10^-4}];
    g[x_] = Interpolation[g1 ][x]

    LogLogPlot[g[x], {x, 10^-9, 4.49/(5*100)}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: What is `PhotonDFx`? Please provide sample code that can be evaluated from start to finish.

Comment: @halirutan : sorry, this is g[x].

Comment: `f` evaluates to zero: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qYsle.png -- In `g1`, you've substituted the argument `q` into the slot for `Z`.  Perhaps that's a mistake?  (If not, I get a constant `0.` for the value of `g`, not a discontinuous function.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 : you're right. Sorry for my mistakes...

Comment: Try `Plot[g[x], {x, 10^-9, 4.49/(5*100)}, PlotRange -> All]` and you'll see that the interpolation goes negative. That's why the log-log plot has a gap.  Try `InterpolationOrder -> 2` or `InterpolationOrder -> 1`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 : thank you! Although strange point doesn't vanish, now the plot is smooth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the interpolation overshoots the x-axis, which makes the log-log plot undefined:

```
Plot[g[x], {x, 10^-9, 4.49/(5*100)},
 Epilog -> {Red, Point@g1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.0005}, All}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Lowering the interpolation order to 1 or 2 is one way that results in a positive interpolation.  Another is to rescale the data:

```
gg[x_] = Interpolation[Log@g1][Log@x] // Exp

LogLogPlot[{g[x], gg[x]}, {x, 10^-9, 4.49/(5*100)},
 Epilog -> {Red, Point@Log@g1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.012], Thickness[0.007]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]